# Is it safe to assume that adjacent fragments in a ViewPager will always have their UI active?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I don't override `offscreenPageLimit` property with `setOffscreenPageLimit` of my `ViewPager`. So, in this case the value of the `offscreenPageLimit` is `1` which is the default value. This means that the app will keep alive both left and right adjacent fragments. Taking above mentioned into account is it safe to assume that `onDestroyView` is **never** called on adjacent fragments(until they are adjacent to the currently visible fragment) and access their UI elements although they are not currently visible.
Thank you!

P.S.
When I say **never** I understand that it still might be called when the system will decide to destroy the entire hosting activity. I mean that it will never be called in normal conditions when the user is just interacting with the currently active fragment

Comment: I'm not sure why you should ever care to know the state of adjacent Fragments as each Fragment should be modular and depending on how the Viewpager was setup the Adjacent Fragments lifecycle could be capped at "Started" or "Resumed".

Answer (score 0):

it is completely safe but [frgamentPagerStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter) will be good to use here instead frgamentPagerAdapter.